# Значение строки srand(time(NULL))

Tags: c

Что означает это строка?

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Генерирует случайное число, используя текущею дату, как параметр, как бы для непредсказуемости результата )

Comment: А можно записать генерацию случайных чисел как-то иначе?

Comment: Я больше по яве - там можно, тут не подскажу, но, думаю, можно.

Comment: Можно!

    mt_rand(); // генерирует десятикратное число типа 7018379426

    rand(); // генерирует число от 1 до 10 типа 589 или 95783 или 27 и т.д.

Comment: Пардон не увидел метку "C") Это на php

Answer (score 14):

Не совсем так, как было написано. Для генерации псевдослучайных чисел используется функция `rand()`. Она генерирует числа на основе базы. Если базу не менять, последовательность псевдослучайных чисел будет одна и та же. Для установки базы генератора псевдослучайных чисел служит функция `srand()`. Ее аргумент - и есть значение базы. Сочетание `srand(time(NULL))` устанавливает в качестве базы текущее время. Этот прием часто используется для того, чтобы при разных запусках генератора псевдослучайных чисел была всякий раз разная база и, соответственно, разный ряд получаемых значений.

Comment: а можно time заменить на что-то другое?

Comment: Можно заменить на что угодно, на любое число, просто этот прием гарантирует, что каждый раз будет разная база. Время ведь при каждом новом запуске меняется.

Comment: На что угодно?? Число?? Или... можете привести пример?)

Comment: Можно число - но когда будешь запускать, посмотри на результат, он всегда будет одинаковый, попробуй вывести случайных 10 чисел и все разы они будут одни и те же, а если параметр время - все 10 раз будет разный.

Comment: из линуксового мана:

#include <stdlib.h>

       int rand(void);

       void srand(unsigned int seed);


The  rand()  function returns a pseudo-random integer in the range 0 to
       RAND_MAX inclusive (i.e., the mathematical range [0, RAND_MAX]).

       The srand() function sets its argument as the seed for a  new  sequence
       of  pseudo-random  integers  to be returned by rand().  These sequences
       are repeatable by calling srand() with the same seed value.

Comment: имеется такая задача:

Даны натуральное число N и последовательность A1, A2, …,A N, AN+1. Определить количество четных чисел, входящих в последовательность A1, A2, …,A N, AN+1.

Написал такой код:

    #include <stdio.h>
    void main()
    {
    int i, num, cout = 0;
    int rand (void);
    void srand(unsigned int seed);
    for (i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    num = rand() % 100 + 1;
    if (num % 2 == 0)
    cout++;
    }
    printf("%d\n", cout);
    getch();
    }

Но выводит все время одно число(

Comment: О чем и речь. При каждом запуске программы функция rand() при неизменной базе будет выдавать при каждом новом вызове неизменный ряд чисел. Прояви самостоятельность, поищи в инете и справочниках, как она работает.